# GeckoFx45 Document Header, Body Are Empty

Tags: c#, winforms, geckofx

I am working on a winforms project in VS2017. I'm using the Geckofx45 Version 45.0.33 Nuget package from 11/17/2017. I've set the project up for 32-bit.

The initializer is coded as:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    ...

    Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");

    ....
}
```

The current proof-of-concept code in the main form constructor currently looks something like this:

```
public MainForm(IConfigurationRoot configuration)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ...

    WebDisplay = new GeckoWebBrowser()
    {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    };

    WebDisplay.Navigate("https://www.google.com/");
    while (WebDisplay.IsBusy)
        Application.DoEvents();

    GeckoHtmlElement payloadElement = WebDisplay
        .Document
        .GetHtmlElementById("viewport");

    ...
}
```

Let's break here and observe the problem. The browser control renders in the form as expected, showing the Google homepage. If I right-click the control for View Source, I see the html I am expecting from the navigation target. Everything checks out in the UX layer.

However, I need to poke around in the DOM, and my queries are all coming back null. Not only does `GetHtmlElementById` fail to return anything, further exploration of the `Document` property (or the `DomDocument` property, or any of the other DOM accessors I've come across) show 2 children on the root (Header, Body), both of which are empty: `WebDisplay.Document.Body.HasChildNodes = false`.

The kicker is, the control is clearly rendering the expected content; it's the API that is failing to show anything but an empty Header and Body element nodes.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I was able to sort this one out. As suspected, this was a timing problem. The attempt to use `IsBusy` (a suggestion I found here on SO) is not sufficient to make sure the DOM is loaded before querying.

In my use case, I need to be able to dynamically render content into the DOM on the first showing of the form. In order to do this, the `DocumentCompleted` event must be used:

```
WebDisplay.DocumentCompleted 
    += new EventHandler<GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs>(WebDisplay_DocumentCompleted);
```

Trying to query the DOM from the form constructor will not work. Cheers!